# ASP.NET MVC: url routing vs querystring

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, query-string

I have a page routed like `/Comments/Search/3` where i search and display all the comments of the thread "3".

I'm adding a sort function (by date, author etc). What is the best way to handle it? `/Comments/Search/3/Sort/Author` or `/Comments/Search/3?sort=author` ?

How do I automatically handle the querystring sort=author as a parameter in MVC?

Thanks

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I prefer: /Comments/Search/3?sort=author. The querystring is a good place to pass in programmatic parameters, especially if the parameter (like in this case) is not important for SEO purposes. If the parameter had some semantic meaning as a search term, the first URL would be better.

In a controller method you can use something like this:

```
public ActionResult Search(int id, string sort)
```

ASP.NET MVC will automatically wire up querystring values to the parameters of your method.

Use the following route

```
routes.MapRoute(
                   "Default",                                              // Route name
                   "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
                   new { controller = "Comments", action = "Search", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
               );
```

/Comments/Search/3?sort=author will call Search(3, "author")

/Comments/Search/3 will call Search(3, null)

Keep in mind that id is mandatory so this url will fail:
/Comments/Search

Comment: I think I'd go for this solution. How do I route it and set a default, as the sort=3 is optional?

Comment: Because of the convention over configuration, keep in mind that your parameters for your method MUST be called 'id' and 'sort' respectively.

Comment: In MVC 2 you can use UrlParameter.Optional and in action parameter use `int? id` instead of `int id` if you want it to be optional and `/Comments/Search` to show the default search UI with empty input text.

Answer (score 20):

ASP.NET MVC will handle that automatically in the query string case. You just add a `string sort` parameter to your action.

Which is better? Personally, I use the path to control the **contents** being displayed and querystring to control the **presentation** (how it's displayed, formatted, ...). So, for sorting, I'd go with the querystring method. But I don't think there's a technical disadvantage in either approach.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to add a routing rule to handle it. There's a handy article on it here:

http://aspalliance.com/1525_ASPNET_MVC_Framework_Part_2_URL_Routing.2

Then your URL would read /Comments/Search/3/Sort/Author