# Routing legacy requests with and without querystring

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

(Before starting: I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7395841) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/817325). I'd like to find a more concise solution -if possible- for a slightly more specific problem)

I'm rewriting an old Webforms app in MVC. As usual, no permalinks should be broken.

I'm using standard `{controller}/{action}/{id}` routes. Legacy paths are usually `SomePage.aspx?ID=xxx`, and I have one particular case where `Foo.aspx` is a list of `Bar` (new URL: **/Bar** or **/Bar/Index**) and 
 `Foo.aspx?ID=xxx` is the `Bar` detail (new URL: **/Bar/View/xxx**)

One possible workaround is adding the following before the Default `MapRoute`:

```
routes.MapRoute("Bar View", "Foo.aspx",
                new { controller = "Bar", action = "View" });
```

And then defining the corresponding action in BarController:

```
public ActionResult View(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    return View();
}
```

There are two problems with this:

- Now, if I create an ActionLink, it uses the legacy format
- I'd like to handle this in the routes; making the id nullable and redirecting in the controller is just wrong

I'm fine with mapping the legacy URLs by hand (I don't need a generic solution and there are only about 8 pages)

This is a new project, so I'm not tied to anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this based on [Dangerous' idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9166539) plus a constraint based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5066466/62024).

My new route table is:

```
routes.MapRoute("Bar", "Bar/{action}/{id}",
                new
                {
                    controller = "Bar",
                    action = "Index",
                    id = UrlParameter.Optional
                });
routes.MapRoute("Bar View", "Foo.aspx",
                new {controller = "Bar", action = "View"},
                new {id = new QueryStringConstraint()});
routes.MapRoute("Bar Index", "Foo.aspx",
                new { controller = "Bar", action = "Index" });
routes.MapRoute("Default", /*...*/);
```

And the QueryStringConstraint couldn't be simpler:

```
public class QueryStringConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route,
                      string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values,
                      RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        return httpContext.Request.QueryString.AllKeys
            .Contains(parameterName, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

Comment: Diego great answer, but no you how to deny urls "Bar/View/3" instead of "Bar/View?id=3"?

Comment: @DenisAgarev I didn't understand your question.

Comment: Sorry to be unclear, I made mistakes in question))) I meant is there a way to allow only querystrings urls like "Bar/View?id=3", because in your solution url like "Bar/View/anything" would be allowed too for same route.

Comment: Everything is possible. But that would be a different question

Answer (score 2):

I believe if you specify the following routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    null,
    "Bar/{action}/{id}",
     new { controller = "Bar", action = "View", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
     new { action = "Index|Next" } //contrain route from being used by other action (if required)
);

routes.MapRoute(
    null,
    "Foo.aspx/{id}",
    new { controller = "Bar", action = "View", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

//specify other routes here for the other legacy routes you have.
```

Then this should solve your first problem.  If the user specifies Foo.aspx in the url then they will be taken to the View action.

If the action link:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click me", "Index", "Bar")
```

is specified then the first route will be used (as the order matters).

However, I could not figure out how to specify if `Foo.aspx?id=...` then to go to one route else if `Foo.aspx` is specified then go to the other route.  Therefore, I would check whether id is null in the action.  However, if you do find this out I would very much like to know.

Hope this helps.